# Sum of all possible numbers of the form 0, ab given a condition

Tags: number-theory

I have this statement:

> Given the relation $0,a\overline b- 0,b\overline a = 0.\overline 4$,
>   with $b$ a digit differen of zero. What is the sum of all the numbers
>   of the form $0,a\overline b$ that satisfies the given relation?

This exercise is done to be solved in less than $3$ minutes, I have solved it in $5$ minutes and for this reason, I would like to see your solutions to learn from these. Thanks in advance.

The correct solution is $3,\overline1$

Comment: What does "$0,a\overline b- 0b\overline a = 0.\overline 4$" mean?

Comment: $0,a\overline{b}$ probably means an infinite repeating decimal $\frac{a}{10}+\frac{b}{10^2}+\frac{b}{10^3}+\frac{b}{10^4}\cdots.$ @lulu Certainly, with that reading, I get an answer of $3,\overline{1}.$ The comma is used in place of decimals in some locales

Comment: @ThomasAndrews  Yes...I thought of that, but that doesn't explain the $0b\overline a$ term.  Well, I suppose that could just be a typo for $0,b\overline a$.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews  Quick calculation, with your interpretation gives $a-b=5$ which does yield $3.\overline 1$ in the end, so I think you've got it right.

Comment: And yes, I assume that $0b\overline{a}$ is a typo for $0,b\overline{a}.$

Comment: Sorry for the error in the question. Edited

Answer (score 2):

(Using US decimal notation, so `.` instead of `,`.

We have: $$0.a\overline{b} = \frac{b}{9}+\frac{a-b}{10}\\0.b\overline{a} = \frac{a}{9}+\frac{b-a}{10}$$

so the difference is:

$$0.a\overline{b}-0.b\overline{a}=\frac{b-a}{9}+\frac{2(a-b)}{10}=(a-b)\left(\frac{1}{5}-\frac{1}{9}\right)=(a-b)\frac{4}{45}$$

When is this equal to $0.\overline{4}=\frac{4}{9}?$

Comment: My solution was, that $a - 5 = b$, and since $a,b$ are digits , with $b \neq 0$ i have $  0 < a \leq  9 \to -5 < a - 5 \leq 4 \to 0 < b \leq 4 $ and the sumatory from $b \in [1, 4]$ in the equation $b/9 + 1/2$ gives the answer. But i think that this solution is long. I need other fastest solutions